# Issue with in groovy script - no file or directory error message

Tags: curl, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

Can anyone help me here. 
I am getting no such file or directory error while running the below groovy script in Jenkins.

```
request1 = ['bash','-c',"curl -v -k -X POST cookies https://hostname/user/login.html -d 'action=login&username=test&pwd=test'"].execute()
request1.waitFor()
println request1.text
```

> above bash command worked and i got the desired output in the jenkins console
>
> but below command didnt work in jenkins groovy script..

I tried this in shell it worked ...

`curl -v -k -X GET -b cookies https://hostname/get-details?action=getDetails&Appname=test`

```
request=['bash','-b',"curl -v -k -X GET cookies https://hostname/get-details?action=getDetails&Appname=test"].execute()
request.waitFor()
println request.err.text // for debugging in jenkins script console
println request.text
```

error:

```
bash: curl -v -k -X GET cookies https://hostname/get-details?action=getDetails&Appname=test: No such file or directory
```

I am using the above script to populate parameter value dynamically based on another paramter using active choice plugin.

Comment: please modify your question and provide the error message. also I guess you try to execute curl - share the code how you  do that.

Comment: edited the question

Comment: i guess you have to split all the parameters to separate array items. like this: `['bash','-b','curl', '-v', '-k', '-X', 'GET', ...]`

Comment: i tried it didnt work. got the error     usr/bin/curl cannot execute binary file

Comment: edit the question, provide command examples and output from command line and from groovy. `cannot execute binary file` - maybe you just don't have access under the jenkins?